# How to save a dynamically generated wallpaper in android

Tags: android, image, dynamically-generated

I am currently developing an app where an image is generated based on the users score in a game. I would like for an option for the user to save the image on to their phone as well as post the image on to facebook.

Is this possible? I cannot find any real documentation.

Thanks.

Comment: for saving an image in the sd card: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887078/android-saving-file-to-external-storage/7887114#7887114

Answer (score 1):

You can make Bitmap from the View Controls like TextView you might be using
- [To Create Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4167593/converting-a-textview-bitmap-imageview-and-nothings-showing-up)

After Creating The Bitmap You can write it to SDCard
- [To Save To SDCard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649154/android-bitmap-save-to-location) - more You can search for this on net

To Upload to Facebook
- [To Facebook Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323496/looking-for-android-facebook-sdk-examples) - more You can search for this on net