# implementing Zoomable TextView in scrollView

Tags: android, textview, pinchzoom

I have a `TextView` inside a `ScrollView` I want to be able to change the font of the `TextView` whenever the user pinches it. I've been searching for a day now and I didn't find anything satisfactory. While I was hopping this to be pretty straightforward. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Try this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10239891/how-to-zoom-a-textview-in-android

and another
http://stackoverflow.com/a/10239924/2931489

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first implement pinch to zoom in `TextView`, you can get some idea from [here](https://code.google.com/p/android-touchexample/) and then as according to the scale value of user pinch try to set textSize of `TextView`. After that immediate disable touch event of `ScrollView` when user pinch or touch to the `TextView`. You can do that in this way(Just use variable instead of true/false return):

```
public class InterceptScrollView extends ScrollView {

public InterceptScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return false;
}

}
```

and when user done with `TextView` then again enable the touch event of `ScrollView`.