# How to wrap a layout having multiple textviews to an image

Tags: android

I am making an app in which I want to make one certificate. For that purpose,I have made one layout with textviews and I want to convert it to an image. How to make an image with multiple textviews?

This is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="500.0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Certificate"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="20.0dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" 
        android:textSize="20.0dp"
        android:textColor="@color/dark_green"
        android:visibility="gone"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/NameText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="70.0dp"
         android:visibility="gone"
        android:text="" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="200.0dp" 
        android:visibility="gone"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="Date:" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="Place:" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By image, what do you mean? Do you want the set of text views to act as a single clickable unit . If so you can write an on click listener for the linear layout .

Comment: No sir,i want to put the view to an bitmap image.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4167593/converting-a-textview-bitmap-imageview-and-nothings-showing-up