# Textview to Image File Android?

Tags: android, image, textview, storage, drawable

I have a `TextView`. I want to change/convert `TextView` into an image file and store it on external storage. Is this possible? How?

Comment: When you say you want to change it into an image file, are you wanting to store an image of the TextView (a picture of the text in it)?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4167593/converting-a-textview-bitmap-imageview-and-nothings-showing-up

Comment: @Blumer : Yeah, i mean it.. TextView -> picture of the text -> store it to to external storage (image file)..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general approach you will want to take is to ...

- Create your `TextView`
- Set its text, font, etc. as you like
- Create a `Bitmap` object with the same dimensions as your `TextView`
- Create a new `Canvas` from your `Bitmap`
- Call the `TextView.Draw(Canvas)` function to render it onto to the canvas
- Save the resulting `Bitmap` to a file

The Android documentation should be able to help you how to accomplish each of those sub-points.

Comment: I was unable to get this to work.  No errors, just the textview never was rendered.  My textview is not shown anywhere on my UI and I was not able to force the layout to occur.  So it was always width zero.  I solved it by using canvas.drawText() and setting up my Paint to match my textView settings.