# Using ImageView as Parent?

Tags: android, android-studio

Is it possible to use an `ImageView` as parent? I want to put a few `TextView`s on an `ImageView` and when the user zooms on `ImageView`, I want `TextView`s to be zoomed too!

Note: I made a zoom-able `ImageView` but i can't make a zoom-able `RelativeLayout`...

EDIT:

my xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <nikdan.m.metro.ZoomableImageView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:id="@+id/imgMap"
         android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <TextView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
         android:text="Hello"
         android:id="@+id/text"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:textColor="#ff0000" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: It should be possible using `setScaleX`, `setScaleY`, `setPivotX`, setPivotY` to make a zoomable View. But I wouldn't expect anyone on stackoverflow to give you the code ready to use.

Comment: If the content of the TextView doesn't change, you could cheat by making the image the ZoomableImageView the cached view bitmap of the framelayout by registering a global pre draw listener

Answer (score 1):

Make `FrameLayout` as the `Parent` and add `TextView`s after the `ImageView`.

That should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks. I don`t know how FrameLayout Works. I guess i should learn!

Comment: Thanks noticing that :)

Comment: i did it but it is still not working. ImageView zooms but TextView does't !

Comment: Never tried it personally but try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4167593/converting-a-textview-bitmap-imageview-and-nothings-showing-up